# Nested TransactionScope for NUnit TestFixure and SetUp

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, transactions, nunit

I derive from this base class in order to enclose each indivdual test into a transaction that is rolled back

```
public abstract class TransactionBackedTest
{
    private TransactionScope _transactionScope;

    [SetUp]
    public void TransactionSetUp()
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
            Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
        };

        _transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
                                                 transactionOptions);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TransactionTearDown()
    {
        _transactionScope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Using this I also tried to setup a TestFixure transaction the same way:

```
[TestFixture]
class Example: TransactionBackedTest
{

    private TransactionScope _transactionScopeFixure;


    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
            Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
        };

        _transactionScopeFixure = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                                                       transactionOptions);


        SetupAllDataForAllTest();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        _transactionScopeFixure.Dispose();
    }


    public void SetupAllDataForAllTest()
    {
        // Sql stuff here that will get undone from the TestFixtureTearDown scope dispose
    }


    [Test]
    public void DoSqlStuff1()
    {
        // Sql stuff here that will get undone from the TransactionBackedTest
    }

    [Test]
    public void DoSqlStuff2()
    {
        // Sql stuff here that will get undone from the TransactionBackedTest
    }
}
```

The idea being that `SetupAllDataForAllTest` is ran once at the beginning and inserts all the base data that tests rely on. This base data needs to be deleted/rolledback once the tests are complete.

I also want each test isolated so they cannot interfere with each other as well.

The issue I am having right now is that after the first test, it states the TestFixture transaction has been closed, even though I only wanted it to close the SetUp transaction. My assumption is that if you `Dispose()` and inner transaction it diposes the outer, so I am not sure how to accomplish what I want to do

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would would you put your tests within a transaction scope and roll it back? Are you testing some database calls but don't want the data committed?

Comment: I am testing calls that do a merge as part of a process, but yes I dont want the merge to be commited.  The overall test has its own transaction because test-data is preloaded. So in transaction 1, test data is inserted, then for each test a merge may happen that shouldnt be commited (test data should be reverted)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what database you use.

In MS SQL Server if you [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188929.aspx) inside another transaction (make them nested) and then [`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) inside the nested transaction, it will roll back everything (the whole outer transaction as well).

> ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without a savepoint_name or transaction_name
>   rolls back to the beginning of the transaction. When nesting
>   transactions, this same statement rolls back all inner transactions to
>   the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION statement.

To be able to roll back only the inner nested transaction it should be started by [`SAVE TRANSACTION <name>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188378.aspx) with some name for the nested transaction. Then you can `ROLLBACK <name>` to roll back just the nested part.

If you are using some other database, it may behave differently in nested transactions.

I have no idea how to make your classes issue correct `BEGIN or SAVE TRANSACTION` SQL statements depending on whether the transaction is nested or not.

Comment: This is sooo true :) I believed for many years that I could actually nest transactions with MS-SQL. I was so wrong.